# angular 2 pipe for track number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-filters, angular2-pipe

I have json like this :

```
[
{
 id : 4
},
{
 id : 3
},
{
 id : 2
},
{
 id : 1
}
]
```

I want in `*ngFor` create a pipe that my template get like this after get rendered (list From small to large According to id)

```
<span><span><=== id =1
<span><span><=== id =2
<span><span><=== id =3
<span><span><=== id =4
```

angular 2 have `PIPE` for this work? or We must create a pipe like this?(HOW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a simple sorting pipe. Of course you could make it more general, too:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'sortById',
    pure: true
})
export class IdSortPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: Array<any>, args:any[]):any {
        value.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.id - b.id;
        });

        return value;
    }
}
```

In your template:

```
<span *ngFor="let obj of array | sortById">id = {{obj.id}}</span>
```

---

> [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xGXotHoIzQ1ZZmXQCAwy?p=preview) for example usage

Answer (score 0):

You should follow angularjs 2 documentation

```
<span *ngFor="let item of array">id = {{item.id}}</span>
```

Assuming your given data is in **array** variable. And before templating sort your array the way you'd like your dom to be shown

Comment: :|||| no men, i mean list From small to large According to id